# media foundation H264 decoder not working properly

Tags: c++, video, decode, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I'm creating an application for video conferencing using media foundation and I'm having an issue decoding the H264 video frames I receive over the network.

**The Design**

Currently my network source queues a token on every request sample, unless there is an available stored sample.  If a sample arrives over the network and no token is available the sample is stored in a linked list.  Otherwise it is queued with the MEMediaSample event. I also have the decoder set to low latency.

**My Issue**

When running the topology using my network source I immediately see the first frame rendered to the screen.  I then experience a long pause until a live stream begins to play perfectly.  After a few seconds the stream appears to pause but then you notice that it's just looping through the same frame over and over again adding in a live frame every couple of seconds that then disappears immediately and goes back to displaying the old loop.

Why is this happening?  I'm by no means an expert in H264 or media foundation for that matter but, I've been trying to fix this issue for weeks with no success.  I have no idea where the problem might be.  Please help me!

The time stamp is created by starting at 0 and adding the duration to it for every new sample. The other data is retrieved from a IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback.

I've also posted some of my MFTrace onto the msdn media foundation forums [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/a14e7435-a414-4a2a-849a-8e2c906d4b17/media-foundation-h264-decoder-not-working-properly?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment/)

I mentioned on there that the presentation clock doesn't seem to change on the trace but, I'm unsure if that's the cause or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:
Could you share the video and a full mftrace log for this issue? It's not clear for me what really happens: do you see the live video after a while?

The current log does not contain enough information to trace sample processing. From your description is looks like that only keyframes are rendered. Plus, duration is weird for the rendered keyframe:

```
    Sample @00A74970, Time 6733ms, Duration 499ms. <- Duration is not 33ms.
```

I would like to see what happened to that sample.

In any case, if you are using standard encoder and decoder, the issue should be with your media source, and how it buffers frames. Incorrect circular buffer implementation? You may want to try and cache a second or two of samples before starting giving them to the decoder.

Comment: I've updated my post to show some of my code.  If it's not enough let me know and I'll add anything else.  Thanks for responding!

Comment: My source is intended to be a live network source (trying to make a video conferencing application), so I've tried two different implementations.  After I create the sample from the network data I either immediately queue the MEMediaSample event with the sample or, I've tried another implementation that checks if I've received a sample request and if I haven't, it loads the sample into a CInterfacelist to be used on the next request (I don't think this ever happens since the stream appears to be rateless).  I experience the same issues regardless.  I'll upload the full trace log shortly.

Comment: On a whim, I changed the characteristics of my source to no longer include MFMEDIASOURCE_IS_LIVE.  It works fine now.  This boggles my mind.  Any idea as to why it acted this way just because of that characteristic?

Comment: If the MFMEDIASOURCE_IS_LIVE, MF will use real-time presentation clock, and discard any late samples. Buffering some samples in advance would have helped to ensure that you don't have late sample drops in the beginning of the playback.

Comment: I've resolved the thread on msdn.  Thanks for your help!  I really appreciate it!