# Playback using Raw Data Bytes Frame by Frame

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I have a stream of bytes encoded by H264.Now I want to playback using Media Foundation I have the frames as raw data without container and I receive it frame by frame.does any one have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at this question which is doing exactly the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653158/media-foundation-h264-decoder-not-working-properly.

Comment: @sipwiz it is different then my case,you have answered correctly for how to get raw data from Sample Reader now I need the inverse

Comment: What's the destination for the decoded frames? A file or on screen display?

Comment: a screen not a file ,After I get the raw data from the file I want to draw it on the screen (I have the bit rate used  and raw data are encoded by H264)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet below demonstrates how to create an IMFSample object from a byte buffer. Once you have an IMFSample it can be fed to the MF Enhanced Video Renderer.

```
MFCreateSample(&reConstructedVideoSample); 
CHECK_HR(MFCreateMemoryBuffer(srcBufLength, &reConstructedBuffer), "Failed to create memory buffer.\n"); 
CHECK_HR(reConstructedVideoSample->AddBuffer(reConstructedBuffer), "Failed to add buffer to re-constructed sample.\n"); 
CHECK_HR(reConstructedVideoSample->SetSampleTime(llVideoTimeStamp), "Error setting the re-constructed video sample time.\n"); 
CHECK_HR(reConstructedVideoSample->SetSampleDuration(llSampleDuration), "Error setting re-constructed video sample duration.\n"); 

byte *reconByteBuffer; 
DWORD reconBuffCurrLen = 0; 
DWORD reconBuffMaxLen = 0; 
CHECK_HR(reConstructedBuffer->Lock(&reconByteBuffer, &reconBuffMaxLen, &reconBuffCurrLen), "Error locking re-constructed buffer.\n"); 
memcpy(reconByteBuffer, srcByteBuffer, srcBuffCurrLen);         // srcByteBuffer is a byte * that contains the sample video data read from file.
CHECK_HR(reConstructedBuffer->Unlock(), "Error unlocking re-constructed buffer.\n"); 
reConstructedBuffer->SetCurrentLength(srcBuffCurrLen);
```